# Typescript: Input object has subset of keys of an interface

Tags: typescript, types

I want to be able to specify that an input object to a function should only contains keys that are present in an existing interface (it does not need to have all the keys).

```
interface Group {
  name: string
}

interface Person {
  id: number
  name: string
  email: string
  age: number
}

interface AddedProperties {
  groups: Group[]
}

function createPerson<D extends object>( // <-- Should convey, D is an object with some keys of Person
  personData: D
): D & AddedProperties {
  return Object.assign({}, personData, { groups: [] })
}

interface NameAndAge {
  name: string
  age: number
}

// Valid: Should be valid
const person: NameAndAge = createPerson({ name: "bob", age: 5 })
// Valid: Should be invalid as 'personality' doesn't exist on Person
const person2 = createPerson({ name: "bob", age: 5, personality: "cheerful" })
```

Is this possible in typescript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I've found the better answer now after some research :-) I'll leave my other answer as well, though. Here's what you can do:

```
function createPerson<D extends keyof Person>(
    personData: Pick<Person, D>
): Pick<Person, D> & AdditionalProperties {
    return Object.assign({}, personData, {groups: []});
}
```

This allows `personData` to be only a strict subset of `Person`, and the return type will be exactly the same structure plus `AdditionalProperties`:

```
createPerson({name: "Bob", age: 5});         // OK
createPerson({name: "Bob", gender: "male"}); // Type error
createPerson({name: "Bob"}).name;            // OK
createPerson({name: "Bob"}).age;             // Type error
```

---

How does it work? The generic `D extends keyof Person` would, once again, allow adding new fields, which we want to avoid. We cannot handle this in the definition of the generic type argument (since we only have `extends` there), but instead limit the actual function argument to

```
personData: Pick<Person, D>
```

This restricts the input to only those properties of `Person` which appear in `D`. We use the same type as the return type (intersected with `AdditionalProperties`).

---

You can see it in action [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Person%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20email%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20createPerson%3CD%20extends%20keyof%20Person%3E(%0A%20%20%20%20personData%3A%20Pick%3CPerson%2C%20D%3E%0A)%3A%20Pick%3CPerson%2C%20D%3E%20%26%20%7Bgroups%3A%20string%5B%5D%7D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20personData%2C%20%7Bgroups%3A%20%5B%5D%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AcreatePerson(%7Bname%3A%20%22Bob%22%2C%20age%3A%205%7D)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20OK%0AcreatePerson(%7Bname%3A%20%22Bob%22%2C%20gender%3A%20%22male%22%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Type%20error%0AcreatePerson(%7Bname%3A%20%22Bob%22%7D).name%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20OK%0AcreatePerson(%7Bname%3A%20%22Bob%22%7D).age%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Type%20error):

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly! Just for how it works, when you said "The generic D extends keyof Person would, once again, allow adding new fields, which we want to avoid." I think that at this point extra fields are already prevented. Suppose person only had keys 'id' and 'name' for brevity, then if D extends keyof Person that means that D can only be one of ('id' | 'name') or ('id') or ('name) or (never).

Answer (score 14):

A simple approach is using `Partial<>`:

```js
function createPerson(
  personData: Partial<Person>
): Partial<Person> & AddedProperties {
  return { ...personData, groups: [] };
}
```

`Partial` takes a type and makes all of its members optional, thus allowing you to specify any subset of properties of that type.

The downside of this typing is that the returned type has no knowledge of what you put into it:

```
createPerson({name: "Bob", age: 5});         // OK
createPerson({name: "Bob", gender: "male"}); // Type error
createPerson({name: "Bob"}).name;            // OK
createPerson({name: "Bob"}).age;             // OK :-(
```

If you want to avoid this as well, check out my other answer.

Comment: With function createPerson<D extends Partial<Person>>() {...},

    const person2 = createPerson({ name: "bob", age: 5, personality: "cheerful" })

is still valid even though personality is not on the Person interface.

Comment: @Lionel Tay Good point. I've updated my answer, which will now disallow that. However, the typing is still maybe not quite what you want since the returned object won't have knowledge of which fields have been set by the input. I'll admit that I don't see a way to achieve this. Perhaps someone else will.